# ApexChart needs very long time to render

Tags: javascript, ajax, loading, dashboard, apexcharts

I have a very weird problem, my goal is to render multiple charts on a dashboard with the help of the Apexcharts-Library. Data source for the Graphs is an async AJAX request.

If I run the Server locally all Graphs on Dashboard are visible ~2s after calling the site,
when running the Server at local Network on Raspberry Pi, the Graphs show up after ~30 seconds, cpu is hardly working during loading. Code is the same on both devices. The data for loading the graphs is available 1-2 seconds after calling the site, so it's not a data-transfer-time problem.

Thank you for your help, tried everything until now, but found no solution for this....

Answer (score 0):

Found the failure, some of the values in the database were datatype string instead of int or float, deleting them solved the problem.

Thread can be closed...